# Is there a way to list all domain names for IIS setup?

Tags: iis, iis-6, domain-name

I have a Windows 2003 IIS6 setup.

I would like to get an extract (system output) of all the header dns entries (virtual hosts etc).

As I need to move my server and just updated the IPs (I don't have direct access to my DNS server as it is managed by our hosting provider, and I can't very well just say "updated all our domains" as we have other servers.

And no, I don't have a pre-existing list, some of this was done before I joined my company.

Thoughts? Is there a way or do I go through manually and do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list the existing sites with:

```
cscript C:\WINDOWS\system32\iisweb.vbs /query
```

Output looks like the following, the `Host` column is the host header value.

```
Connecting to server ...Done.
Site Name (Metabase Path)                     Status  IP              Port  Host
================================================================================
Default Web Site (W3SVC/1)                    STARTED ALL             80    N/A
directory.example.com (W3SVC/2)               STARTED ALL             80    directory.example.com
```

Here is the Technet for [`iisweb.vbs`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728368%28WS.10%29.aspx) as well as the [Managing Web Sites Using Scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739153%28WS.10%29.aspx) parent article.

Comment: Great! Yep that's what I need :)
Will accept your answer once it lets me (currently saying minimum 5 min)